# Auto-complete show everything by default

Tags: ajax

I have an field of "User reference" on a content type -- using an auto-complete control. This works but our user list is in the order of 300+ and it's difficult to remember who all should be selected for various tasks.

Auto-complete by default shows a list only once you have entered a single character -- is it possible to have the list show everyone the minute you click the text field???

Comment: Why not use a view for the entity selection. Set up a entity reference page in a view and include other fields about the user such as department etc. Then set to search on all of these extra fields in views and now you can at least search by other grouping factors and not just users.

Answer (score 1):

Mabye you can use the Chosen module :

- Install, enable and configure the [Chosen module](https://www.drupal.org/project/chosen)
- change the widget type of your field to "Select list"
- in the field settings screen, check "apply chosen on this field" : 
  [image]

Now in your content edit form, you should see something like this, where the entire list appears in the dropdown, but where you can also type an autocomplete request :

[image]

Comment: I tried the module...unfortunately it doesn't seem to register as a field type or control type...but rather applies to all select's -- in which is won't work in my case.

Comment: yes, Chosen does not create a field type or widget... You must use a select list as the widget for your field, and then in the settings of the field, check "apply chosen on this field". And you can disable chosen for other selects in the module settings page, by chosing "never apply" on the 3 first settings.

Comment: Ya I figured that out...it's not quite going to work though. I have a user field (ie: called assigned) and that originally was a multi-select listbox -- then converted to auto-complete text box...I need the multi-select capability.